# Strange behavior of PSConsoleReadLine

Tags: powershell

Trying to seemingly generate text in Powershell console (result predetermined), did not like cls + Write-Host because of constant blinking, tried to use PSConsoleReadLine. Code below works in some situations, while it does not in others.

Code works when:

- directly copy pasted into Powershell window
- when stored in a script file and the file is called from Powershell window

Code does not work when:

- launched in ISE (known issue)
- right click on the script file / run with powershell

Tried to get around the error with Add-Type, but it ends with IOException and null reference instead. Is present in code below, but commented.

Tried to write a script in a way that relaunches itself in a new Powershell process to handle it, did not help.

Code itself (probably could reproduce the issue with a single line of code, but the guide says one line of a code is not enough):

```bsh
 function tryOne($oldExpression, $targetExpression, $currentPosition, $src)
{ 
    While($targetExpression[$currentPosition] -cne $triedCharacter)
    {
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()#here problem
        $triedCharacter = Get-Random -InputObject $src
        $expression = $oldExpression + $triedCharacter
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert($expression)#here problem
        Start-sleep -Milliseconds 50
    }
    Return $expression
}
cd $PSScriptRoot
#Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadline\1.2\Microsoft.PowerShell.PSReadLine.dll"
#above helps with not found error, with it uncommented the errors at RevertLine and Insert are IOException and null reference
$targetExpression = "Not ideal"
$oldExpression = ""
$currentPosition = 0

#region AllowedCharacters
    $src = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    for($i=65;$i-le 90;$i++)
    {
        $src.Add([char]$i) | Out-Null
    }
    for($i=97;$i-le 122;$i++)
    {
        $src.Add([char]$i) | Out-Null
    }
    for($i=0;$i-le 9;$i++)
    {
        $src.Add($i) | Out-Null
    }
    $src.Add(" ") | Out-Null #allowed characters in the target sentence - A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space
#endregion

While($currentPosition -lt ($targetExpression.length))
{
$oldExpression = tryOne $oldExpression $targetExpression $currentPosition $src
$currentPosition++;
}
```

I'd like to be able to launch the script via right click / run with Powershell.

Comment: There is a way to use carriage return character. ```Write-Host "`r" $expression -Separator "" -NoNewline```

Comment: Yup, thanks for info. Just I'd add one thing: do not try this in ISE console, because it does not work in there, this stuff works in normal Powershell console. I did not try Visual Studio Code.